# What does 哈批 mean?

Tags: slang, internet-slang

My Chinese friend said 哈批 but I don't understand what it means. When I googled, it showed 哈麻批 and it seems a dirty word.

The whole sentence is something like the follows:

> This person is bullshit! He doesn't understand my language??? (with a screenshot from 微信）
>
> I: Because it is not human; it must be AI.
>
> She: 哈批

My question is, what is 哈批? Is it different from 哈麻批?

And on what kind of situation is it used?

FYI she is Chongqingnese and she seems to like such a dirty word...

Comment: web search with 哈麻批, e.g. https://www.zhihu.com/question/30240096

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pretty much just the South Western Mandarin pronunciation of: 傻逼/傻屄/傻毴.

Check out these two entries from Guang'an Topolect dictionary:

> 《广安方言与民俗词典》
>
> 词语: 傻
>
> 发音: ha3
>
> 定义: 傻“sha3”的音变。常说成“哈”。指愚蠢、老实、呆。如“哈儿”、“哈巴儿”、“哈戳戳”、“哈宝器”、“哈婆娘”、“哈得很”、“哈话”、“吃哈亏”等。
>
> 俗语：“哈人有哈福”，指傻子往往有福气、好运。

and

> 《广安方言与民俗词典》
>
> 词语: 屄
>
> 发音: pi1
>
> 定义: 屄“bi1”的音变。指女性外阴，又说“麻屄”、“麻批”，常用“麻花儿”一词含蓄替代，容易与成语“麻痹大意”发音闹笑话。民间常用女性生殖器骂人，这种语言现象，应当大力清除。
>
> 俗语：“屄话”，指废话。
>
> “屄娃儿”，骂不懂事、不中用的男子。
>
> “屄嘴巴”，骂人嘴巴爱乱说或贪吃。
>
> “卖屄的”，骂女人生活作风不检点。
>
> “好吃屄”，指特别喜欢吃的人。
>
> 歇后语：“笋壳卡裤裆——屄垮卵垮”，指多嘴，废话多。
>
> “牛屄上的虱子——两边吃”，比喻左右两边的利益都能占。常用于开玩笑或骂人。
>
> “内裤头撒花椒——麻屄”，指女性私处。也常作为骂人粗俗语。
>
> “尿桶头起波浪——屄风<疯>发了”，又说“尿桶头起波浪——屁眼儿风<疯>发了”，均为极其粗俗的骂人语，比喻言语、行为似乎发疯，让人难以接受。“尿桶”，指盛装尿便的木桶。旧时的农家房屋，厕所大都在室外，为了方便晚上大小便，卧室内大多会放上尿桶临时解决内急。同时，担运动物粪便等农家肥时，尿桶也是一种运输工具。

Now that we've got the pronunciation part figured out what does SB mean?

Literally it means stupid (傻) + cunt (屄) and [MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=1&wdqb=shabi) corroborates the literal meaning:

> 傻屄
>
> shǎ​bī​
>
> stupid cunt (vulgar) / also written 傻逼

---

Just as a side note `批` in the Chongqing dialect is more likely to be pronounced `pēi` than `pī` - for instance: 批发 is read as `pēi fá` not `pī fá` because of the vulgarity connected to the `pī` pronunciation.

Answer (score 1):

> 哈批 https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%93%88%E6%89%B9
>
> “哈批”是、贵州、四川、重庆的方言，带有贬义色彩，可以用来骂人，有“笨蛋、傻瓜”的意思。比如你要说一个人傻的话！你就可以说你是个哈批“你是个哈批”就意思是你是傻瓜或者笨蛋的意思。还有意思相近的口语哈麻批

Translation:

> "哈批" is, Guizhou, Sichuan, Chongqing dialect, with a derogatory tone, can be used to curse people, "idiot, stupid".
>
> For example, if you want to say a person is silly, You can say that "you are a 哈批" which means "you are a fool or idiot". Another version of this term is "哈麻批"

In Short, "哈批" is a slang for "stupid" in Guizhou, Sichuan, Chongqing regions

Answer (score 1):

It is a dirty word from dialects of central China.

It's the equivalent of 笨蛋 "stupid" or 傻瓜 "idiot".

A quick [search on Uncle Google](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%93%88%E6%89%B9) reveals the mystery.

Answer (score 1):

哈皮 can also mean “happy”.  It is more likely the case in online chat.  Special dirty words from dialects are seldom used online.

Answer (score 0):

It is a phonogram word in many dialects, not only in Sichuan. In my home, Xi'an, people speak 哈 instead of 坏, but 哈 is not the real word, it is a phonetic symbol of the word **bad** (坏) in our dialect. The character 批 is similar as 哈. The word 哈批 or 哈皮 just like the common word 傻逼, the character 逼 is also a phonetic symbol. The sound 批 or 皮 has the same meaning as the character 逼. So, we speak 这个人哈得很, which means 这个人很坏, and using 你妈的批 instead of 你妈的逼.